How to write an SQL query to retrieve data of the people who turned 65 last week?
I want to retrieve the data of the users who turned 65 in last week. I have just birth_date column in the table to get the data. There is no other date column. And I need to use today's date to compare the birthdate of the users from who have turned 65 in the last 7 days.
I tried below query but got no result:
select *
from table
where birth_date < current_date - 65


Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See this to know why tagging is important.

The RDBMS is Oracle.

If someone turned 65 in the last 7 days, their birthdate is between "now minus 65 years - 7 days" and "now minus 65 years"
Your query searches for people born 65 days ago.
Try this:
select *
from table
where birth_date between sysdate - numtoyminterval(65, 'year') - 7
  and sysdate - numtoyminterval(65, 'year')

See live demo.

Depending on what does it realy mean "... the people who turned 65 last week?" - the code below could cover the last week beeing either current iso week or previous iso week or last 7 days:
WITH   --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, BIRTH_DATE) AS
        ( Select 1,   To_Date('17-04-1958', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 2,   To_Date('18-04-1958', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 3,   To_Date('19-04-1959', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 4,   To_Date('20-04-1959', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 5,   To_Date('21-04-1959', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 6,   To_Date('22-04-1959', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 7,   To_Date('23-04-1959', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual Union All
          Select 8,   To_Date('24-04-1960', 'dd-mm-yy') From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select  ID, 
        EXTRACT(Year From SYSDATE) "SYS_YEAR",
        To_Char(SYSDATE, 'iw') "SYS_ISO_WEEK", 
        To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, (65 * 12)), 'yyyy-iw') "YR_ISO_WEEK_65",
        Trunc(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(BIRTH_DATE, (65 * 12))  "DAYS_FROM_65"
From    tbl

/*    R e s u l t :
        ID   SYS_YEAR SYS_ISO_WEEK YR_ISO_WEEK_65 DAYS_FROM_65
---------- ---------- ------------ -------------- ------------
         1       2024 17           2023-16                 376
         2       2024 17           2023-16                 375
         3       2024 17           2024-16                   8
         4       2024 17           2024-16                   7
         5       2024 17           2024-16                   6
         6       2024 17           2024-17                   5
         7       2024 17           2024-17                   4
         8       2024 17           2025-17                -362   */

... this resultset could be filtered to whatever "last week" is in this case. Something like:
... ...
WHERE DAYS_FROM_65 Between 0 And 7  -- Or 1 And 7 maybe
-- OR
... ...
WHERE SYS_YEAR || '-' || SYS_ISO_WEEK = YR_ISO_WEEK_65
-- OR
... ...
WHERE SYS_YEAR || '-' || (SYS_ISO_WEEK - 1) = YR_ISO_WEEK_65

